# Does my logo design look well in composition?

Tags: logo

I am a self-taught logo designer. The image below is an exercise logo for study purpose. I want to deep dive my understanding of composition, do you have a think about this?

[image: Roboto logo]

Comment: Hi Mardika, welcome to GD.SE, I think you should add information about the conceptual meaning of the logo. As your question is formulated now, the only possible answers will be regarding formal aspects without any base or meaning. We don`t know anything about the typography election, the colors, the graphics, what the image represents, etc.

Comment: Also I would recommend you reading some [logo critiques](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=logo+critique) questions in this site